# How to change image's href with Javascript by using title name?

Tags: javascript, css, href

Here in this slideshow there are around 50 images. I use a platform which is similar to wordpress and doesnt let me to change image href. The images have the same class name. Is it possible to use title name(which is unique for each image) and change some image's href?

```
<div id="slideshow" class="vlt-d-slider" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 928px; height: 522px;">
    <div class="slide" data-vltcaption="0" data-brand="none" data-topic="INST" data-url="_0.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; visibility: visible; z-index: 3; line-height: 520px; height: 522px;">
<a class="slide-lightbox" rel="vlt-slideshow" href="m_0.jpg" title="Pfusc number photo 1" target="_blank">
<img class="slide-img" src="_0.jpg" alt="Pfusc number photo 1">
</a>
</div>
      <div class="slide" data-vltcaption="1" data-brand="none" data-topic="INST" data-url="0.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 1; line-height: 520px; display: block; height: 522px;">
<a class="slide-lightbox" rel="vlt-slideshow" href="f_0.jpg" title="Pfusc number photo 2" target="_blank">
<img class="slide-img" src="0.jpg" alt="Pfusc number photo 2">
</a>
</div>
      <div class="slide" ....
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean alt attribute by title ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, images don't have `href`, they have `src`.

Secondly, I think you mean `alt` when you say "title name"?

In that case, `document.querySelector('[alt="the title"]').src = 'the new src';`

If you want to find it by the title of the link, you would have to do `document.querySelector('a[title="the title"] > img').src = 'the new src';`

Comment: you could simplify it by using `('a[title="the title"] > img')` and avoiding the second query selector.

Comment: Thanks, @funcoding edited it! OP, you should take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ to get a hang of these basics in no time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For start I'm not sure do you want to change your `a tag` or `img tag` properties, but I will presume it's `a tag` because of you mentioned `href`. Yes it is. You can do it like this:

```
$("a[title='yourTitle']").attr('href', 'https://www.google.com/');
```

and if you want image:

```
$('img[alt="Your Alt"]').attr('src', 'image.jpg');
```

Comment: You are asuming, that jQuery is available, without even mentioning jQuery.

Comment: You are right I will adjust code if OP requires vanilla.